# why div is breaking during zoom in browser?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to develop responsive theme using wordpress but I div break when I am doing zoom in browser.I am giveing some css code :

```
   .here {
        background: url("images/header-opacity.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 100;
    }
container_24 {
  max-width:980px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  z-index:10;
  /* border-radius:5px; /* L */
}

.grid_24 {
   width: 99%;
}

.grid_24 {
  width: 99%;
}

.topsearch {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 22px;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.toplinks {
  float: right;
  font-size: 0.83em;
  max-width: 688px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear 0s, color 0.2s linear 0s;
}
```

I am giving my site http://bassbrushes.diggsdev.com/blades/.I am unable to find any solution.Any idea would help me lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think %100, %99 values causes to this problem. if you change .container_24 .grid_24 it'll be ok.

```
.container_24 .grid_24 {
    width: 980px;
}
```

Comment: My theme is responsive,if I used above, will it create any problem

Comment: Also break div name page-overlay,here is the property I used.
.page-overlay {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -8%;
    width: 100%;
}